# KeyboardInterrupt - is it safe for copied data

Tags: python, numpy

I have a loop where in each iteration I (re)calculate a long vector of values:

```
try:
    while(1):
        long_vec = recalculate( long_vec )
        last_vec = long_vec.copy()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print last_vec
```

`long_vec` and `last_vec` are numpy arrays.

My question is: can I be sure that when I press CTRL+C , it won't break copy() function, and `last_vec` is not broken?

Comment: Ctrl+C can only break Python code.  So this depends on whether `long_vec.copy()` is implemented in Python or C.  You'll have to look at NumPy's source code -- or wait for someone to do this for you. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: :) I believe it is in C , but let consider the worst general case, that all is in Python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the `.copy()` that matters, it's the subsequent assignment of the reference (`last_vec =`) that does.

I believe the assignment is atomic in CPython (i.e. it requires a single bytecode instruction).

In other words, `last_vec` can either contain the value from the previous iteration, or the copied value from the current iteration. Pressing Ctrl-C cannot result in `last_vec` containing a partial copy of the new value.

Comment: You are right, the atomicity of the assignment is what matters.  (And it is atomic, the bytecode being a `STORE_NAME` instruction.)

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure it is copied using the `finally` block:

```
while True:
    try:
        long_vec = recalculate(long_vec)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print long_vec # last_vec == long_vec in your example
    finally:
        # does not make sense, since the program halts after that:
        last_vec = long_vec.copy()
```